# How to use Python to scrape all the table contents on this website which is written by AJAX?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, web-scraping

https://www.fedsdatacenter.com/federal-pay-rates/index.php?y=2017&n=&l=&a=&o=

This website seems to be written by jquery(AJAX). I would like to scrape all pages' tables. When I inspect the 1,2,3,4 page tags, they do not have a specific href link. Besides, clicking on them does not create a clear pattern of get requests, therefore, I find it hard to use Python urllib to send a get request for each page.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: _Use of Material
Content is herein defined as any text, graphics, or material within the Site. The format of the Site and the content is copyright protected and shall not be reproduced on any other web site or reprinted in any manner without express written consent from FedSmith Inc._

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium with Python http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ to navigate through the pages. I would find the Next button and .click() it then time.sleep(seconds) and scrape the page. I can't navigate to the last page on this site, unfortunately (it seems broken - which you should also be aware of), but I'm assuming the Next button disappears or something when you get to the last page. If not, you might want to save the what you've scraped everytime you go to a new page, this way you don't lose your data in the event of an error.

Comment: Thank you! I am totally new to programming (economics major), didn't expect someone to answer my stupid question... I will try my best to learn it. Wish I can figure this out!